# RxJS Observable fromPromise and interactive loop in CLI app

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, rxjs

I'm building a simple command line tool using node.js.

In the past, I was using a Promise approach with something like this

```
function listenCommand(){
    inquirer.prompt([{
        type:'input',
        name:'value',
        message:"Enter commande :"
    }]).then(function (command) {
        processCmd(command);
    });
}

function processCmd(){
   ...
   listenCommand()
}
```

That would create my main loop to enter commands. When a command is executed the app will ask for a next one.

I'm now trying to transpose that into a RxJS approach with something like.

```
function listenCommand(){
    let listener = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(inquirer.prompt([{
        type:'input',
        name:'value',
        message:"Enter commande :"
    }]));

    listener.subscribe(function (command) {
        processCmd(command);
    });
}

function processCmd(){
   ...
   listenCommand()
}
```

It works but that doesn't sounds good.

What is the *right* way for doing this *prompt loop* with RxJS? Or is RxJS not suited for that kind of job and should I stick to the *Promise* approach instead?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach you suggested is essentially the first approach, you have just wrapped the promise in an Observable interface. You probably want to use the `repeat/repeatWhen` operators:

```
function listenCommand() {
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => 
    inquirer.prompt([{
      type:'input',
      name:'value',
      message:"Enter commande :"
    }])
  )
  // Repeats until the end of time
  .repeat()
  .subscribe(cmd => processCommand(cmd))
}
```

On the caller side you can cancel the operation at any time by doing:

```
const subscription = listenCommand();

subscription.unsubscribe();
```